# How to change default location of struts.xml in Struts 2?

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, configuration-files

I want to know how to change default location of struts.xml in Struts 2?
Thank for your help!

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to change the default location of the xml file? Its location shouldn't matter to your webapp

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question, the filter configuration accepts a "config" parameter that specifies the location(s) of S2 configuration files:

https://struts.apache.org/docs/webxml.html

<strike>http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/webxml.html</strike>

Answer (score 2):

Did you have a look at the documentation?

[Here](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/strutsxml.html) it says that struts.xml `should reside on the classpath of the webapp`, so the location shouldn't matter, as long as it is in the classpath.

Additional link: http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/struts-1-solutions.html (Note that although it says Struts 1 Solutions it talks about Struts 2 - it's more of a migration guide)

Answer (score 1):

Struts only needs to be in the class path of the webapp. Its location is irrelevant.